# Audio file in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, audio, joptionpane

I am trying to make a champion select like League of Legends for my senior project in Java.  I have done well so far in my opinion but I am stuck on something.  I want to try whenever a JOptionPane is opened to play a sound file.  I have done some research throughout the day but don't see many people trying it.  I saw something about a beep through JOptionPane but that is about it.  Any ideas?

```
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
   {
      @Override

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

         if (actionCommand.equals("Aatrox"))
         {
                 playPopupMessageSound();
                 final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\EventObjectWindow\\src\\eventobjectwindow\\Resources\\Aatrox.png");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Aatrox."+System.lineSeparator()+ "Aatrox is a legendary warrior, one of only five" +
                         "that remain of an ancient race known as the Darkin."+System.lineSeparator()+"He wields his massive blade with grace and poise, "+""
                         + "slicing through legions in a style that is hypnotic to behold."+System.lineSeparator()+"With each foe felled, Aatrox's seemingly" +
                         "living blade drinks in their blood, empowering him and fueling his brutal, elegant campaign of slaughter." +System.lineSeparator()+
                         "Base stats:" +System.lineSeparator()+ "Health: 537.8 (+85 per level)                             Health Regen: 6.59 (+0.5 per level)"
                         +System.lineSeparator()+ "Attack Damage: 60.376 (+3.2 per level)         Armor:24.384 (+3.8 per level)" +System.lineSeparator()+
                         "Attack Speed: 0.651 (+3% per level)               Magic Resist: 32.1 (+1.25 per level)" +System.lineSeparator()+
                         "Movement Speed: 345", "Aatrox", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon);            
         }
         else if (actionCommand.equals("Ahri"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Ahri");
         }
         else if (actionCommand.equals("Akali"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Akali");
         }
         else if (actionCommand.equals("Alistar"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Alistar");
         }
         else if (actionCommand.equals("Amumu"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Amumu");
         }
      else if (actionCommand.equals("Anivia"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Anivia");
         }
      else if (actionCommand.equals("Annie"))
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have selected Annie");
         }}
   }




public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      EventObjectWindow em = new EventObjectWindow();
   }
   protected static void playPopupMessageSound() {

        try (InputStream is = EventObjectWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SrProjectLeague\\src\\srprojectleague\\Sounds\\Aatrox.wav")) {
            try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is)) {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }}
      public static class PlayPopupMessageSound implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            playPopupMessageSound();
        }
}}
```

Comment: Write a wrapper class which takes the most common parameters you need for a `JOptionPane`, construct it yourself and play the sound before you display it

Comment: I'm pretty inexperienced in Java so could you maybe elaborate a bit more, sorry.

Comment: I did, it's all in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Start by having a look at [Sound Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) for more information about how to use the audio API.

The basic idea is to try and play the sound before you show the dialog, but this may mean the sound finishes before the dialog is actually made visible (like a noticeably long time).

We can use a `Thread` to try and delay the playing of the audio, but I simply used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and that seemed to work pretty well.  My machine was under a considerable load, so you're testing might find different results and require some additional tweaking.  The size of the audio file may also play a role, so be wary of that.

Next, I created a simple convince method, which would play the audio associated with the popup and show the dialog, to make life simpler, for example...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                showMessage(null, "Be happy", "You are now happy");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showMessage(Component parent, String title, String message) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PlayPopupMessageSound());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, message, title, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }

    protected static void playPopupMessageSound() {

        try (InputStream is = TestMessage.class.getResourceAsStream("/audio/TaDa.wav")) {
            try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is)) {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static class PlayPopupMessageSound implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            playPopupMessageSound();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind if I emailed you with my code so you could take a look at it? I'm not sure where I am messing up.

Comment: I just did, it probably is really stupid and I have never used sound files before.

Comment: Change `"C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\SrProjectLeague\\src\\srprojectleague\\Sounds\\Aatrox.wav` to something more like `"/srprojectleague/Sounds/Aatrox.wav"`

Comment: I really wasn't worried about using the Utilities or anything.

Comment: In me "experimentation", if I didn't use `SwingUtilities` or `Thread`, the sound play WAY before the dialog was displayed, `SwingUtilities` just allowed me to delay the playing to some time in the future, which generally made the two (sound and dialog) work better together

Comment: So what I am trying to do, is when the button is pressed to open the option pane, the sound will play. Can you see where I am messing up at?

Comment: Not really.  The code I've presented works fine for me.  Does the dialog show up when you press the button?  Do you get any exceptions?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses